# How do I split a column by using delimiters from another column in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have another question that is related to the split function.
I am new to Spark/Scala.

below is the sample data frame -

```
+-------------------+---------+
|             VALUES|Delimiter|
+-------------------+---------+
|       50000.0#0#0#|        #|
|          0@1000.0@|        @|
|                 1$|        $|
|1000.00^Test_string|        ^|
+-------------------+---------+
```

and I want the output to be -

```
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|VALUES             |Delimiter|split_values          |
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|50000.0#0#0#       |#        |[50000.0, 0, 0, ]     |
|0@1000.0@          |@        |[0, 1000.0, ]         |
|1$                 |$        |[1, ]                 |
|1000.00^Test_string|^        |[1000.00, Test_string]|
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
```

I tried to split this manually -

```
dept.select(split(col("VALUES"),"#|@|\\$|\\^").show()
```

and the output is -

```
+-----------------------+
|split(VALUES,#|@|\$|\^)|
+-----------------------+
|      [50000.0, 0, 0, ]|
|          [0, 1000.0, ]|
|                  [1, ]|
|   [1000.00, Test_st...|
+-----------------------+
```

But I want to pull up the delimiter automatically for a large dataset.

Comment: Please add what you have tried and what failed for you in the question. You should provide a minimal reproducible example with your question.

Comment: I know that it can be done manually based on the above sample data frame -
```
dept.select(split(col("VALUES"),"#|@|\\$|\\^").show()
```

and the out put does match but I don't want to put the delimiter manually.

Comment: what doe the logic for extra column ?

Comment: @dsk I have edited the question. I am not sure about the logic for the extra column as of now. My main concern is with the automatic fetching of the delimiters for large data sets.

Comment: A UDF would probably work here.

Comment: @Shashwat - Pls see the ans below - Please do not hesitate to accept and upvote in case you are happy with the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **`expr`** with **`split()`** to make the split dynamic

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("50000.0#0#0#","#"),("0@1000.0@","@")],["VALUES","Delimiter"])
df = df.withColumn("split", F.expr("""split(VALUES, Delimiter)"""))
df.show()

+------------+---------+-----------------+
|      VALUES|Delimiter|            split|
+------------+---------+-----------------+
|50000.0#0#0#|        #|[50000.0, 0, 0, ]|
|   0@1000.0@|        @|    [0, 1000.0, ]|
+------------+---------+-----------------+
```

Comment: This is a really cool answer. What is the import for `F`? is it `regex.F`? I couldn't get it working.

Comment: Hi @PubuduSitinamaluwa function expr() is under spark.sql.functions. You can directly import expr or can use alias to call the expr().
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, @dsk I think we have to include escape characters for other cases to handle '$', '^' etc.

Comment: @PubuduSitinamaluwa from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

Comment: @Shashwat Will Appreciate if you can accept the answer :) Glad that it helped you

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Please check the bottom of the answer for scala version.

You can use a custom user-defined function (`pyspark.sql.functions.udf`) to achieve this.

```py
from typing import List

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType


def split_col(value: StringType, delimiter: StringType) -> List[str]:
    return str(value).split(str(delimiter))


udf_split = udf(lambda x, y: split_col(x, y), ArrayType(StringType()))

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('50000.0#0#0#', '#'), ('0@1000.0@', '@'), ('1$', '$'), ('1000.00^Test_string', '^')
], schema='VALUES String, Delimiter String')

df = df.withColumn("split_values", udf_split(df['VALUES'], df['Delimiter']))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output

```
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|VALUES             |Delimiter|split_values          |
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|50000.0#0#0#       |#        |[50000.0, 0, 0, ]     |
|0@1000.0@          |@        |[0, 1000.0, ]         |
|1$                 |$        |[1, ]                 |
|1000.00^Test_string|^        |[1000.00, Test_string]|
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
```

Note that the `split_values` column contains a list of strings. You can also update `split_col` function to do more changes to values.

**EDIT :** Scala version

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

import spark.implicits._

val data = Seq(("50000.0#0#0#", "#"), ("0@1000.0@", "@"), ("1$", "$"), ("1000.00^Test_string", "^"))
var df = data.toDF("VALUES", "Delimiter")

val udf_split_col = udf {(x:String,y:String)=> x.split(y)}

df = df.withColumn("split_values", udf_split_col(df.col("VALUES"), df.col("Delimiter")))

df.show(false)
```

**Edit 2**

To avoid the issue with special characters used in regexes, you can use char instead of a String when using the `split()` method as follow.

```scala
val udf_split_col = udf { (x: String, y: String) => x.split(y.charAt(0)) }
```

Comment: OP is asking for Scala ;)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But the concepts are the same.

Comment: Sure but not everyone is able to "translate" Python to Scala.

Comment: I agree. Let me come up with a scala version of it.

Comment: @Shashwat Hope you were able to solve the issue. I added a sample of scala version of it.

Comment: Thanks @PubuduSitinamaluwa both method works really well.

Comment: Hi @PubuduSitinamaluwa I think we have to include escape characters for other cases to handle '$', '^' etc.

Comment: Good point. Or you can change the Delimiter column type to char if it is always a single character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234871/discussion-between-shashwat-and-pubudu-sitinamaluwa).

Answer (score 2):

This is another way of handling this,using sparksql

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")

spark.sql("""select VALUES,delimiter,split(values,case when delimiter in ("$","^") then concat("\\",delimiter) else delimiter end) as split_value from test""").show(false)
```

Note that I included the case when statement to add escape characters to handle cases for '$' and '^',otherwise it doesn't split.

```
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|VALUES             |delimiter|split_value           |
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|50000.0#0#0#       |#        |[50000.0, 0, 0, ]     |
|0@1000.0@          |@        |[0, 1000.0, ]         |
|1$                 |$        |[1, ]                 |
|1000.00^Test_string|^        |[1000.00, Test_string]|
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my lately solution

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
val split_udf = udf((value: String, delimiter: String) => value.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter), -1))
val solution = dept.withColumn("split_values", split_udf(col("VALUES"),col("Delimiter")))
solution.show(truncate = false)
```

it will skip special characters in Delimiter column.
Other answers not work for

```
("50000.0\\0\\0\\", "\\")
```

and linusRian's answer need to add special characters manually

Answer (score 1):

### Enhancing @dsk Answer to handle two more cases.

---

### Scala Code

**`First Case:`** To handle special characters `('$' ,'^')` we need to add escape Characters backslash `'\\'` as prefix on Delimiter column, like this below..

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr
val new_deptArray = dept.withColumn("split_values",expr("""split(VALUES, Concat('\\',Delimiter))"""))
new_deptArray.show(truncate = false)
```

And this will be the Output.

```
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|VALUES             |Delimiter|split_values          |
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|50000.0#0#0#       |#        |[50000.0, 0, 0, ]     |
|0@1000.0@          |@        |[0, 1000.0, ]         |
|1$                 |$        |[1, ]                 |
|1000.00^Test_string|^        |[1000.00, Test_string]|
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
```

**`Second Case:`** Notice that few rows got that extra space at the end and ideally, we don't want them. so, this new column `split_values` is of type `Array<String>` and we can just use `array_remove` to remove these extra spaces.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{expr, array_remove}
val new_deptArray = dept.withColumn("split_values",array_remove(expr("""split(VALUES, Concat('\\',Delimiter))"""), ""))
new_deptArray.show(truncate = false)
```

it will give this output.

```
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|VALUES             |Delimiter|split_values          |
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|50000.0#0#0#       |#        |[50000.0, 0, 0]       |
|0@1000.0@          |@        |[0, 1000.0]           |
|1$                 |$        |[1]                   |
|1000.00^Test_string|^        |[1000.00, Test_string]|
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
```

---

### Pyspark Code

It worked almost same in pyspark also just the difference was we need to add four backslashes backslash `'\\\\'` unlike Scala where only two backslash was sufficient.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, array_remove
new_deptArray = dept.withColumn("split_values",array_remove(expr("""split(VALUES, concat("\\\\",Delimiter))"""), ""))
new_deptArray.show(truncate = False)
```

---

```
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|VALUES             |Delimiter|split_values          |
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
|50000.0#0#0#       |#        |[50000.0, 0, 0]       |
|0@1000.0@          |@        |[0, 1000.0]           |
|1$                 |$        |[1]                   |
|1000.00^Test_string|^        |[1000.00, Test_string]|
+-------------------+---------+----------------------+
```

Thanks.